# No Output in uibModal in {{...}}

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-modal

After creating a Form Modal with Input its working fine.
But now a Simple Modal to Delete is showing nothing.

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="delete.html">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Löschen {{this.selectedKey}}{{$ctrl.this.selectedKey}}{{ctrl.this.selectedKey}}
          {{$ctrl.this.selectedKey._id}} {{ this.selectedKey._id }} | {{ctrl.this.selectedKey._id}}?</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Sind sie sich sicher das sie diesen Key: {{$ctrl.selectedKey.Name }} löschen wollen ?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete()">Löschen</button>
        <button class="btn" ng-click="close()">Abbrechen</button>
      </div>
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
// Modals
deleteKey(selectedKey) {
  this.$uibModal.open({
    scope: this.$scope,
    templateUrl: 'delete.html',
    controller: ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', '$http', 'selectedKey', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, $http, selectedKey) {
      this.selectedKey = selectedKey;
      this.$http = $http;
      $scope.close = function() {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
      };
      $scope.delete = () => {
        this.$http.delete('/api/dict_keys/' + selectedKey._id);
        window.location.reload();
        $uibModalInstance.close();
      }
    }],

    resolve: {
      selectedKey: () => {
        return selectedKey;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

It is getting the selectedKey and deleting it. But in my Modal there is no output of this key to show which is now Selected.
Like you can see I tried several things in .html as {{with controller/without}}.
In .js sending the selectedKey as resolve. Injecting it in Controller and so on.

Where did I miss something or did wrong ?

Solution:

**Controller**

```
 deleteKey(selectedKey) {
        this.$uibModal.open({
          scope: this.$scope,
          templateUrl: 'delete.html',
          controller: ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', '$http', 'selectedKey', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, $http) {
            $scope.selectedKey = selectedKey;
            this.$http = $http;
            $scope.close = function() {
              $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
            };
            $scope.delete = () => {
              this.$http.delete('/api/dict_keys/' + selectedKey._id);
              window.location.reload();
              $uibModalInstance.close();
            };
          }],
          resolve: {
            selectedKey: () => selectedKey
            }

        });
      }
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="delete.html">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Löschen {{selectedKey.Name}}?</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    Sind sie sich sicher das sie diesen Key: {{selectedKey.Name}} löschen wollen ?
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="delete()">Löschen</button>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="close()">Abbrechen</button>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: controller you specified is which controller. I guess this is the controller which calls modal for delete. is it? Which is controller you used for deleteModal

Comment: Yes, in Controller is the inline Controller and if not NamedAs the Default is $ctrl. I tried as well with
`controller: some code
controllerAs: ctrl,`
As you can see as well implemented in the .html but that didnt work as well.
What have i to do just to simple show in the Modal the {{selectedKey.name}} ?
But the inline Controller is getting the selectedKey Object because $delete is working fine.